# Most efficient way to check whether a square matrix is full rank

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, rank

I'm currently dealing with a problem in which I have to routinely check a large number (1000+) of 8x8 square matrices to see whether they are full rank or not.

I'm not actually interested in the rank, only in it being the maximum or not. What would be the most efficient algorithm to find out?

--Edit--
More info about the matrices: they are, unfortunately, arbitrary; neither symmetric nor sparse. Not only that, but some of the coefficients are evaluations of hyperbolic functions, so usually very large numbers. The symbolic version of the problem has already been dealt with, trying to simplify rows and columns as much as possible (and trying to substitute as many sinh and cosh as possible with tanh.)

Comment: Welcome to SO!... Are those matrices arbitrary or sparse or symmetric or anything else?

Comment: Thanks! I added some info to the question.

Comment: Are those matrices at least positive definite? If so you can use the Cholesky Algorithm for Gaussian Elimination, which is faster in computation as a naive approach.

Comment: I thought Cholesky only works for symmetric positive (semi-)definite matrices, and they are not symmetric.

Comment: If you had millions of 8x8 matrices, it *might* be faster to compute their determinants on a GPU with a naive algorithm like Leibniz's formula, and compare them to 0.  Even though this involves $O(n!)$ work instead of $O(n^3)$ for Gaussian elimination, it avoids any conditional branches and thus can run at top speed on a GPU.  (The conditional branches can cause the same slowdown on a CPU, but the effect is smaller there.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker That is actually very interesting, though luckily I don't need to make that many calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Gaussian elimination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) to convert the matrices to triangular from. If during this process any diagonal element becomes 0, then the matrix has smaller rank.

Because you have so many independent matrices, you can easily do parallelized calculations (easy = minimal synchronisation between threads).

Comment: Parallelized calculations are a very interesting bonus I didn't think about. Do you have any suggestion as to what values should reasonably be considered 0, when appearing on the diagonal during GE?